# How do sites output an html comment to the console

Tags: javascript, html, web-deployment

I see lots of sites now outputting some huge ascii text comment to the console usually saying we're hiring or something similar. The comment is embedded in the html too.

See:

http://www.theguardian.com/uk
https://de.khanacademy.org/

How do they do this? Is it part of some framework/library?

Comment: `console.log('hello');`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/console

Answer (score 1):

As your commenters have noted, those are simply clever uses of the common `console` API, most succinctly expressed with `console.log('hello');`. See http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/console as /u/px5x2 suggests.

As for creating the ASCII art itself, you can use any of a number of online ASCII art generators, such as http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Big&t=Your%20comment

Comment: hmmm... I thought it was some special function of some library as all the sites that do this have the comment on the same place - outside the html tag but after the doctype. I guess all they are doing is just like people here have said, finding the first comment node and outputting it. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Yeah, while Figlet does work, it is frankly total overkill for a single-use static comment, and I'd bet $100 that most folks just use raw console statements. And oh, no, they are definitely, definitely not finding the first comment node and outputting that. That would be terribly fragile. Most likely they simply have it in the HTML and also have it as a set of JS console commands. I would absolutely recommend against trying to find a node in a DOM and just printing that to the console.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/figlet. It has both text to ASCII conversion and can output directly to console.

Here is an example from their npm page:

```
var figlet = require('figlet');

figlet('Hello World!!', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Something went wrong...');
        console.dir(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(data)
});
```

Outputs:

```
 _   _      _ _        __        __         _     _ _ _ 
 | | | | ___| | | ___   \ \      / /__  _ __| | __| | | |
 | |_| |/ _ \ | |/ _ \   \ \ /\ / / _ \| '__| |/ _` | | |
 |  _  |  __/ | | (_) |   \ V  V / (_) | |  | | (_| |_|_|
 |_| |_|\___|_|_|\___/     \_/\_/ \___/|_|  |_|\__,_(_|_)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, never heard of figlet before!